# Controlar estado de contenido vacio, sin conexión en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

¿Cómo se puede controlar los estados que puede afectar el contenido en Android? es decir, las pantallas `Sin contenido, sin internet, no encontrado...`

Tengo un layout que se compone de una `ImageView(image), TextViewtitulo y TextView(sumario)`, centrado en pantalla

Me gustaría que esa fuera una plantilla, es decir que se le puede pasar parámetros, icono, titulo e sumario y remplazar la vista que haya actualmente.

Partiendo que ya tengo funciones que devuelven `true` o `false` dependiendo de como esta la conexión `hasInternetConnection()` o bien disponible el contenido `hasContent()`

Ejemplo visual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es decir ¿quieres detectar si hay conexión a internet o no?

Comment: Eso ya lo tengo lo de detectar, es más digamos como cargar la UI determinado del estado que se encuentre, sin conexion muestre imagen, titulo y sumario, y si hay conexión la interfaz normal

Comment: Como veo que usas tabs y por lo tanto supongo que usarás Fragments ¿por qué no usas un Fragment cuando no haya conexión y otro distinto para tu interfaz normal? Después simplemente sería mostrar uno u otro dependiendo de si hay conexión o no.

Comment: Mmm no había caido que usando fragments es más fácil que usar activity, pero si la vista es una sola activity alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Si algo es más fácil, ¿para que complicarlo? De todas formas si quisieras sí o sí hacerlo con Activity la opción de @Joacer es tu solución.

Comment: Me parece que tengo el dia un poco espeso, jejejej me tomaré un descanso antes de volver al lio.

Comment: jajajaj  eso nos pasa a todos, la solución que da @Error404 creo que es más fácil e igual requiere un poco menos de lógica que la que te he dicho, pero eso ya depende de lo que necesites tu en la aplicación. Saludos

Comment: @Webserveis las 2 opciones son válidas, depende de los requerimientos usar una u otra, si es una vista como un texto dentro de un layout puede ser cambiar unicamente su visibilidad o contenido. Si se necesita cambiar un layout mas complejo la opción podría ser una transacción de Fragments .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que una aproximación podría ser que tuvieras en la declaración de la interfaz del usuario las dos vistas, la de conexión y la de si conexión y una de ellas con el atributo `android:visibility="gone"`. Y después en la actividad dependiendo de si tienes conexión o no hagas una visible y la otra la ocultes o viceversa. Utilizando `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` o  `setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Answer (score 2):

A pesar de que ya hay una respuesta aceptada y tu haces uso de `Activity` voy a poner otra opción por si le puede servir a alguien usando `Fragments`.

En caso de que uses `Fragments` para los Tabs en vez de `Activities` lo que podrías hacer sería crear dos `Fragments`: uno para cuando no haya conexión y otro para la interfaz normal y después reemplazar un `Fragment` u otro dependiendo de si hay conexión y contenido o no.

Algo parecido a esto:

```
if((hasInternetConnection() == true) && (hasContent() == true)){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment,new InterfazNormalFragment()).commit();
}else{
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment,new ErrorFragment()).commit();     
}
```

partiendo de que `R.id.contentFragment` es el contenido anterior que quieres reemplazar e `InterfazNormalFragment()` y `ErrorFragment()` son las clases para tu interfaz normal y el error respectivamente.

Comment: Muy buen aporte, sería otra forma muy buena de hacerlo